# Rails - namespaced migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have the following model and migration:

```
class Content::Panels::Iframe < Content::Panel
  ## Associations ##
  belongs_to :panel_holder, polymorphic: true

  ## Validations ##
  validates :uri, presence: true

  ## Methods ##
  def self.plural_name
    'iframe_index'
  end
end

class AddHeightToIframes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :iframes, :height, :integer, after: :headline
  end
end
```

The migration fails as there is no table called 'iframes'. After googling I've tried adding to the iframe class:

```
self.table_name_prefix = 'content_panels_'
self.table_name = 'content_panels_iframes'
```

and changing the table title to 'content_panels_iframes', However neither of these work when tried independently or together.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a name of the table where this records are stored?

Comment: This isn't surprising -- your model inherits from `Content::Panel`. When using Single Table Inheritance, the base model class typically matches the table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the table name is `content_panels_iframes`, the migration should be:

```
add_column :content_panels_iframes, :height, :integer, after: :headline
```